# Spring Tool Suite 4 Install - Assist

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Looking for assistance with Spring Tool Suite(STS)4 install. When I try to extract the downloaded jar file, I get a pop up window with the message, "How do you want to extract it?". It also gives me the option to 'keep using the app or try more apps' - see attached screenshot for ref. I'm not sure why it's doing that and I thought it should just extract the jar file. I'm on Win 10, Java version is 'java version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18' and I have jdk-19. Finally, I don't know where it's finding the 'jdk-17' in the window in the screenshot. I checked the directory and program files which turned up nothing.

Anyone know how to properly install STS4 on Win 10? Appreciate the help.

[image: 1]

I tried reinstalling the jdk and downloading the STS4 again, but to no avail. I also tried running this command, but it didn't work: $ java -jar spring-tool-suite-4-4.17.1.RELEASE-e4.26.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile spring-tool-suite-4-4.17.1.RELEASE-e4.26.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar

Answer (score 1):

The "self-extracting" jar contains a main method, so you should be able to just run that JAR file with the "java -jar " command from the command line or double click on it. When it runs, it will extract the STS installation on its own, so there is no need or reason to extract the JAR file manually.

If executing the JAR file via "java -jar ..." doesn't work (you mentioned an error message), then it looks to me like a problem with either the downloaded JAR file or some permissions issue.

There is also another way to get the distribution on your machine if the self-extracting JAR file doesn't work. You can go to https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Previous-Versions and download the ZIP file instead of the self-extracting JAR file. But you need to make sure that you extract the ZIP file using a tool like 7zip or so that is capable of extracting ZIP files with entries with very long paths in it. The default built-in unzip of Windows might fail to extract everything into the right place.

Comment: Hey Martin, I followed the steps you proposed and STS is now installed successfully on my machine. As mentioned, I downloaded the 7zip and then grabbed the distribution from the github repo. I was then able to exact the ZIP files and complete the install.  I appreciate you responding to my question for assistance with it. Thank you!